# Installing Ubuntu as dual boot on SED (self encrypting drive) SSD with existing Win7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, ssd, disk-encryption

My 6430u Dell laptop will arrive with a 256 GB Self-Encrypting Drive (hardware encryption, opal). Can I install Ubuntu in a dual boot configuration?

With a normal dual boot, I just boot off a CD or USB, partition and install beside the existing Win OS, using Grub to choose which OS I use. Can this be done with a preexisting Win installation on one of these new type of drives? Can I partition the drive with Gparted etc?

Comment: *Probably.* If you want to make sure before you install anything "exotic", you can try to boot off a Linux live CD and see if you can access anything on the drive. If Linux tools running from a live CD can do as much as read the partition table properly or identify the file system, you'll be fine installing in a dual-boot configuration as far as the drive is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

I found the post below which shows it is possible, but one needs to boot the live CD/USB drive after the first boot step has completed the unlocking process. This is done by waiting until the windows boot sequence starts, then reinitating it, having first set the bios to be able to boot from these media). So not straightforward, but seems possible.

https://plus.google.com/103342596752795218521/posts/Aaku51Ejbu7

Jake